# Change the xslt file of an xml file using php

Tags: php, xml, xslt

hi every one i want to change dynamically the style sheet of my XML file using PHP 
some thing like this:
[the XML file register.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJgX3.png)

when i try to display it it shows me:
[the out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXTEy.png)

OK here is what i want to do :
1) As i mentioned before i have an XML file named "regiter.xml"
2) Let say that i have 3 files with the extension .xsl ( style1.xsl,style2.xsl, style3.xsl )
3) And i have a sort of form tag that give the user the choice of how he want to display the XML file, he can choose  style1 or 2 or 3.
4) **I want to change the value of the attribute href="file.xsl" in the tag <?xml-stylesheet ?> of the file "register.xml" dynamically depending on the user choice**.

my question is:
it is possible to do so?
if not can you suggest me another way to do this?
thank you...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What do you mean by a "style sheet of my XML file"?

Comment: okey i have different file with the extension .xsl for exemple style1.xsl style2.xsl and style3.xsl <br/> and i have an XML file called register.xml <br/> what i want to do is to display "register.xml" with the different styles <br/> let say i have 3 button if i click the first one it will it will link "style1.xsl" with "register.xml" , if i click the second one it will link "style2.xsl" .....

Comment: Please add all such explanation to the question itself, not to the comment section

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to include the text of the error message as that text will be searchable and potentially let others with the same problem find this question and its eventual answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider having PHP run the XSLT scripts and not modify a processing instruction for the browser to render the stylesheet.

```
// LOAD XML SOURCE
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('Input.xml');

// CONDITIONALLY SELECT XSLT SCRIPT
if (if(isset($_POST['button_1']))) {
    $selected_xsl = "/path/to/style1.xsl";

} elseif (if(isset($_POST['button_2']))) {
    $selected_xsl = "/path/to/style2.xsl";

} elseif (if(isset($_POST['button_3']))) {
    $selected_xsl = "/path/to/style3.xsl";

}   
$xsl = new DOMDocument();
$xsl->load($selected_xsl);

// INITIALIZE AND RUN TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($doc);

// OUTPUT NEW XML TO SCREEN
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo $newXML;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it give me the folowing error:
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 6: Extra content at the end of the document

Comment: <br/>List of persones is set ........<br/><br />
<b>Recoverable fatal error</b>:  Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string in <b>/var/www/html/xmlProject/controller/infoController.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />

Comment: i have commented the header("Content-type: text/xml") and it works 
I didn't know why .... 
but thanks you